# i can't locate the class name element on firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Screenshot of error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Can someone help me?
I have tried many ways but still not working

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr').send_keys("good") #change to your comment text
```

Page element source:

[image: Element]

Comment: Can you update the question with the url you are trying to access?

Comment: Is the element you want to interact an textbox/input?

Comment: First of all, after the process you want to do, if possible, can you share the link of the page?

Comment: The error and code should be posted as text **not** as a screen shot. Images are not text-searchable. You say that you have "tried many ways" - list them so that others do not suggest  solutions that you have already tried, thereby wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 0):

when locate element by class name, and the name with `space`, there are several ways to lcate

1. find the name only exists in the target element
2. write like this: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".cls1.cls2")`
3. or this way: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='cls1 cls2']")`